# How to Share media file on Twitter using gigya on Android

Tags: java, android, gigya

I am facing problems in sharing media file using Gigya on Twitter. Please look below at the code snippet.
It is giving a error code as 0 but on the post, only text is getting posted.

```
private void share(){
    GSObject userAction = new GSObject();
    userAction.put("title", "Text");

    GSArray mediaItems = new GSArray();
    try {
        mediaItems.add(new GSObject("{\"src\":\"http://www.f2h.co.il/logo.jpg\", \"href\":\"http://www.f2h.co.il\",\"type\":\"image\"}"));
        userAction.put("mediaItems", mediaItems);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    GSObject params = new GSObject();
    params.put("userAction", userAction);
    params.put("enabledProviders", "twitter");
    GSAPI.getInstance().sendRequest("socialize.publishUserAction", params, new GSResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGSResponse(String method, GSResponse response, Object context) {

            if (response.getErrorCode() == 0) {
                Log.d( "Twitter Auth Token","Session token Response Error ");
            } else {
                Log.d( "Twitter Auth Token","Session token Response Error "+response);
            }
        }
    }, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

I don't think there is a solution for this issue. 
Please look in Gigya documentation and examples:
1. [Share](http://developers.gigya.com/010_Developer_Guide/18_Plugins/032_Share). 
2. [Advance share](http://developers.gigya.com/010_Developer_Guide/60_Sharing/020_Advanced_Report).

Answer bellow is incorrect.

**End EDIT**

It seems that you may be missing the 'type' in the mediaItems object.
Please look in Gigya [documentation](http://developers.gigya.com/020_Client_API/010_Socialize/010_Objects/UserAction_object#MediaObject).

The output user action json should look like this:

```
{
    'title' : 'text',
    'mediaItems' : [{
            'type' : 'image',
            'src' : 'http://www.f2h.co.il/logo.jpg',
        }
    ],
}
```

Comment: Type is already mentioned new GSObject("{\"src\":\"http://www.f2h.co.il/logo.jpg\", \"href\":\"http://www.f2h.co.il\",\"type\":\"image\"}")

Comment: My bad, haven't noticed that part.

Comment: I think it is a Tweeter issue, because I've tried publishing this action to Facebook and media was posted.

Comment: Yes problem is related to twitter. Even from native side, we have to download file and have to share File type object to share via twitter. Is there any other solution available to post media file using Gigya on twitter

Answer (score 1):

Gigya does not support uploading and sharing an image within a tweet. The recommended approach would be to include a link to the image within the tweet itself.

Hope this helps